# Word/Phrase for something to be grateful for

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

Context, I'm drafting a condolence note for a friend whose grandfather just passed. They were close, which I think is something to be grateful for, since a lot of people only have distant relationship with grandparents.

Of course "blessing" is the obvious choice, but in the circumstances the religious connotation is inappropriate.

Comment: "gift" or "privilege"

Comment: Please explain in your question what how you are going to use the word you are looking for. A title is not a question.

Answer (score -1):

**Commendable**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/commendable):

> deserving praise

In your case you could say:

> Since a lot of people only have distant relationship with grandparents, I think your having been so close is really **commendable**.

Attribution: "Commendable Meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary." Cambridge Dictionary. Accessed April 27, 2018. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/commendable.

Comment: The poster is looking for a word like "blessing". "Commendable" doesn't fit.